Orthogonal singlet states?
I recently encountered a problem where the inner product of the two product states
$|0,0\rangle\otimes|0,0\rangle$ and $|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle\otimes  |\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}\rangle$
results in $0$.
$\langle0,0|\otimes\langle0,0|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle\otimes  |\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}\rangle=\langle0,0|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle\langle0,0|\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}\rangle=0$
However, when I write both product states as a sum of irreducible representations using Clebsch-Gordon coefficients, I get:
​$$ \langle 0,0|\left(\frac{|{1,0}\rangle+|0,0\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=0$$
This implies $\langle0,0|0,0\rangle=0$.
Can this be correct? I thought there is only one irreducible representation of the singlet, so how can singlets from different product states be orthogonal? Is there an issue in my reasoning or in my understanding of spin states?
Addition
There is some doubt that a Spinor and scalar can live in one Vectorspace and therefore the inner product used in the first equation
could not be  well defined. So now I want to use just integer angular momenta. Theses states (represented by spherical harmonics) form an orthonormalbase of the hilbert space of square-integrable functions on the unit sphere. So the inner product of two states with diffrent angular momentum should be well defined.
So the inner product of
$$\langle0,0|\otimes\langle0,0|1,0\rangle\otimes  |1,0\rangle=\langle0,0|1,0\rangle\langle0,0|1,0\rangle=0$$
is $0$ as well.
In coupled states this relation can be written as
$$\langle0,0|\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|2,0\rangle-\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}|0,0\rangle\right)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}\neq0.$$

What are the two vector spaces that you're taking the tensor product of?  If your product states "live" in a product space $V \times W$ then you have both $|0,0\rangle \in V$ and $|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle \in V$, and similarly $|0,0\rangle \in W$ and $|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle \in W$.  That seems like a category error for basic angular-momentum problems, but there might be some weird context in which it's valid.

So you think that the Spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particles can not live in a vectorspace together? I honestly do not know if its possible to create such a vector space. But what is for example with the product state $\langle1,0|\otimes \langle1,0|0,0\rangle\otimes|0,0\rangle=0$ There should definetly be a Hilbertspace in which both states can live in. The product states seems orthogonal, but by changing the base to the coupled states you have another contradiction (see CG table).

Can you explain the notation a bit more? As others have pointed out (if I understand them correctly), are you sure that all of your vectors are from the same Hilbert space?


Is there an issue in my reasoning or in my understanding of spin states?

In both. You are abusing Dirac notation, meant to defocus from side issues and omit other labels (and bases of tensor calculus in favor of the states' transformation laws under rotations). I'll go through all steps fussily. No need to go to your additional edit.

$$
|A\rangle= |0,0;v\rangle\otimes|0,0;w\rangle\\
|B\rangle= \vert \tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};v\rangle\otimes  |\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{-1}{2};w\rangle,
$$
where the left Hilbert space V is three-dimensional,
consisting of the three states
$|0,0;v\rangle;  |\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};v\rangle ; |\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{-1}{2};v\rangle$, while the right one, W, consists of the three states
$|0,0;w\rangle;  |\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};w\rangle ; |\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{-1}{2};w\rangle$.
Your full tensor product Hilbert space, H, then, is 9-dimensional, accordingly.
$\langle A|B\rangle=0$, as you saw, while $|B\rangle$
is part of a 2$\times$2 quartet, with Clebsch components in the spin triplet, $|1,0;h\rangle$ and the spin singlet $|0,0;h\rangle$, as you observe. This singlet has nothing to do with A, also a singlet.
Analytically, your total Hilbert space consists of 9-vectors, which, when it comes to spin, break up into a direct sum of five blocks, now characterized by their dimensionality,  3⊕ 1⊕2⊕2⊕1,
originating in: 2⊗2  for the first two summands, 1⊗2 and 2⊗1 for the next two, and 1⊗1 for the last one, identifiable with A.
It is then manifest that the first singlet is completely disjoint, and hence orthogonal, to the second one.
